# Tune spark performance while writing big data to csv

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi :) I have this code in spark /scala that partitions big data ( more than 50GB) by category into csv files.

```
  df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .partitionBy("CATEGORY_ID")
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("sep", "|")
  .option("quoteAll", true)
  .csv("output/inventory_backup")
```

The dataframe df is the result of aggregations on imported data from a csv file :

```
   df.groupBy("PRODUCT_ID","LOC_ID","DAY_ID")
  .agg(
      functions.sum("ASSORTED_STOCK_UNIT").as("ASSORTED_STOCK_UNIT_sum"),
      functions.sum("SOLID_STOCK_UNIT").as("SOLID_STOCK_UNIT_sum")
  )
```

I would like to tune the performance of this program. Through Spark UI , I was able to see that the bottleneck of performance occurs at the stage that exports the data into csv files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBWUG.png)

More details = I'm using a 16cores/120GB RAM instance

Do you guys have any ideas on how to tune the performance ? (It currently takes more than 17min). 
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with this code, other than than using `csv` as a storage format.

Comment: I added some details about the instance I'm using. It has to be a csv file ( it's more of a business requirement ). My question is : can I improve the level of parallelism ?

Comment: Have you tried to export on HDFS and then copy to local? Also, have you tried to use a different number of instances/different instance types?

Comment: No I didn't try with HDFS , I'm working with standalone spark that interfaces with S3. Yes I've tried different instance types, but what I would like to do is to improve spark's performance , not upgrade the instance type.

Comment: The shuffle write size is pretty large comparing to the data size, ~16Gb vs 50Gb. I suspect  the performance may be suffering because of this, not because of saving to disk. E.g. try inserting df.persist(); df.count() before calling df.write to force lazy aggregation to complete and see how long does it take to save after that.

Comment: Will do thanks Denis !

Comment: After some investigations , it seems like it's reading the csv file that takes most of the time . I commented the aggregations part and just tried to import and export data, and I'm still carrying the huge shuffle writes. Any ideas how to make reading the csv more efficient ?